# Boundary Homomorphism Orientation (Very Basic Homology Question)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

In this $\Delta$-complex (Taken from Hatcher pg 102), it is calculated that $\partial_2 U=-a+b+c$.

My short question is, could it be $\partial_2 U=a-b-c$ instead? How do we know which is correct, or are both equivalent?

Thanks.

Comment: Ignoring for the moment how you computed the boundary, you see that the two choices you've written differ by a sign only, so when you quotient out the kernel by the image to get the homology you don't change anything with a sign difference on one of the relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $\Delta$-complex, the vertices of any simplex come with an ordering, and this ordering is used in defining the boundary map.  Conventionally, when you draw a picture like the one you've drawn, all the edges are labelled with arrows so that they are pointing from the lower vertex to the higher vertex, with respect to the ordering.  Looking at $U$, this means the simplices of $U$ are ordered (bottom left, top right, top left).  By definition, in the boundary of a simplex, each face appears with a sign $(-1)^i$, where $i$ is the index in the order of the vertex you've left out.  So the edge $b$ of $U$, obtained by omitting the $0$th (bottom left) vertext, gets a sign $(-1)^0=+1$, $a$ gets the sign $(-1)^1=-1$, and $c$ gets the sign $(-1)^2=+1$.  In total $\partial_2 U$ is $b-a+c$.